# PHP MySql Insert columns form one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert my table data from copying another table with some new given data.

I use this query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2(name, city, email,money) 
   hasib,SELECT table1.city, table1.email, 
   newsletter_subscribers.email 
   FROM table1 WHERE name='jesy',100";
```

But its not Work

Comment: I see 2 tables you are trying to insert from.Anyway spend some time on a basic sql tutorial.

Comment: 1. Do you have a question, and 2. You cannot just make up syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You must give *all* columns inside the select statement columns, even constant values, e.g.

```
insert into table2(name, city, email, money)
select 'hasib', city, email, 100
from table1
where name = 'jesy'
```

If you want to take values from multiple tables, as your select statement suggests, you must look into [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)s.